# How to set Application Name to be 2 (or more) lines on iOS Home Screen?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When developing with Xamarin, I understand that in order to change the app name on Home Screen I need to change "CFBundleDisplayName" property value on "info.plist".
If the name is to long, is there a way to break line?

Answer (score 2):

No. If the name is too long to be displayed, iOS will shorten it.